# scrapy-cluster : socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python, docker, scrapy

I am trying to run scrapy-cluster following [this quick-start.](http://scrapy-cluster.readthedocs.io/en/dev/topics/introduction/quickstart.html)
I am getting following error.

```
# python rest_service.py
2017-02-01 03:02:20,009 [rest-service] INFO: Successfully connected to redis
2017-02-01 03:02:20,011 [rest-service] INFO: Running main flask method on port 5343
2017-02-01 03:02:20,014 [rest-service] INFO: Closing Rest Service
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rest_service.py", line 711, in <module>
    rest_service.run()
  File "rest_service.py", line 449, in run
    self.app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=self.settings['FLASK_PORT'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 843, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 694, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 656, in inner
    fd=fd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 550, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 464, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, (host, int(port)), handler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 417, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
    SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 431, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

How should I use another port.

Answer (score 1):

You could check which process is using that port using 
`sudo netstat -nlp | grep :5343`

and then kill that process using its PID 
`kill -9 <pid>`

Answer (score 0):

Go to localsettings.py in rest cluster and change FLASK port

Not sure why cluster starts with port 5343 already in use by python and not able to kill

regards